# Bivariate stopped processes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Take two **dependent** Levy processes $L_1(t)$ and $L_2(t)$ with law $\mathcal{L}(L_1(1),L_2(1)$. If we stop the first process at a general time $t=s_1$ and stop the second process at another general time $t=s_2$ can we say anything about the distribution of the random variables $(L_1(s_1),L_2(s_2))$?

Any reference will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

**Edit :** The bivariate process $(L_1,L_2)$ is assumed Levy as well.

**Edit :**
The time the process is stopped is a deterministic time.

This is what I worked out.
The characteristic function of $(L_1(s_1),L_2(s_2))$ can be written as:

\begin{equation}
E[exp(i(u_1L_1(s_1)+u_2L_2(s_2))]=E[exp(i(u_1L_1(s_1)+u_2L_2(s_1)+u_2I(s_2-s_1))]
\end{equation} for $s_1<s_2$ and I(t)representing the increment from $s_1$ to $s_2$ in the component $L_2$.

Next, we condition on $I$ (or better on the filtration generated by it)(this might be a problem) :
\begin{equation}
E[exp(i(u_1L_1(s_1)+u_2L_2(s_1)+u_2I(s_2-s_1))]=E[e^{iu_2I(s_2-s_1)}E[e^{i(u_1L_1(s_1)+u_2L_2(s_1)}|I]]
\end{equation} 
Now, by the properties of Levy processes we get:
\begin{equation}
E[e^{iu_2I(s_2-s_1)}E[e^{i(u_1L_1(s_1)+u_2L_2(s_1)}|I]]=E[e^{iu_2I(s_2-s_1)}e^{s_1\Psi_{L_1,L_2}(u_1,u_2)}]=e^{s_1\Psi_{L_1,L_2}(u_1,u_2)}E[e^{u_2I(s_2-s_1)}]=e^{s_1\Psi_{L_1,L_2}(u_1,u_2)}e^{(s_2-s_1)\Psi_I(u_2)}
\end{equation} 
where  $\Psi_{L_1,L_2}$ and $\Psi_I$ are the characteristic exponents of the respective processes.

Can you spot any mistakes or flaws in the above reasoning? Thank you.

Comment: Why should the equality $$\mathbb{E}[e^{\imath (u_1 L_1(s_1)+u_2 L_2(s_1)} \mid I] = e^{s_1 \psi_{L_1,L_2}(u_1,u_2)}$$ hold?

Comment: Because when we condition on I in the expression $E[E[e^{i(u_1L_1(s_1)+u_2L_2(s_1)}e^{iu_2I(s_2-s_1)}|I]]$, we can take $e^{iu_2I(s_2-s_1)}$ outside the first expectation, due to measurability arguments, and we are left with $E[e^{i(u_1L_1(s_1)+u_2L_2(s_1)}]$, which is the characteristic of a Levy process evaluated at time $s_1$, so we get $e^{s_1\Psi_{L_1,L_2}(u_1,u_2)}$, where $\Psi_{L_1,L_2}(u_1,u_2)$ is the characteristic exponent. Did I make a mistake here somewhere?

Comment: We can pull out $e^{\imath \, u_2 I(s_2-s_1)}$, that's correct; but this leaves us with $$\mathbb{E}(e^{\imath \, (u_1 L_1(s_1)+u_2 L_2(s_2)} \mid I),$$ i.e. the *conditional* expectation. This does not equal $$\mathbb{E}e^{\imath \, (u_1 L_1(s_1)+u_2 L_2(s_2))}.$$

Comment: Right, I see what you mean. The reason I did got that is because I believe that I and $L_2$ are independent due to some "independence of increments" sort of argument, which is kind of strange in this context because when we condition on $I$, we are actually conditioning on the future of the process. So, what I am saying is some sort of strong Markov property should give me that.However, I need to formulate that in the right way. Do you think this is wrong?(it is definitely vague but I hope you get more or less what I ment)

Comment: Yes, I get it. Actually, the problem is $L_1$. For the factor $e^{\imath \, u_2 L_2(s_2)}$ we could use in fact the independence of the increments, but unfortunately we don't know anything about the relation of $L_1(s_1)$ and $I$ - they might be dependent.

Comment: But, if you think of some sort of filtration argument, the filtration generated by I should be independent of the one generated by $(L_1,L_2)$ up to time $s_1$ by the same arguments as above, or at least that's my intuition. In my opinion there is no reason why $L_1$ should depend on something in the future since we have a Levy process here and the increments are independent. Does it make sense?

Comment: $L_1$ does not depend on its own future, but it might depend on the future of $L_2$. Simple Example: Let $L_2(t)$ be an arbitrary Lévy process, then $L_1(t) := L_2(t+a)-L_2(a)$ defines a Lévy process ($a>0$ fixed) which depends on the future of $L_2$.

Comment: I don't know if the example you gave does really show the dependence on the future. The process $L_1(t):=L_2(t+a)−L_2(a)=L_2(t)$, so the bivariate process $(L_1(t),L_2(t))$ is couple of comonotone processes but they don't depend on the future of each other. Anyway, I guess in general they can't depend on the future, otherwise they won't be measurable wrt the filtration generated by them, right? Am I wrong on this? do you have any reference where I can see other examples like this?

Comment: You didn't mention that they are measurable with respect to a common filtration.

Comment: I did not. But isn't this true for any bivariate Levy process?

Comment: But I didn't say the bivariate process $(L_1,L_2)$ is Levy either, so I guess is fair that you assumed they might not. Sorry my mistake.

Comment: You also didn't mention that $(L_1(t),L_2(t))_{t \geq 0}$ is a bivariate Lévy process.

Comment: Apart from that, does the rest look alright to you? Thanks for getting involved in the discussion.

Comment: Yeah, in this case your calculation is correct. (Actually, I thought that you are interested in the case that the process is *not* bivariate Lévy.)

Comment: I really appreciate your involvement. Good luck with your PhD!

Comment: No, Levy case is enough for my purposes.